# Can you use an abstract function in an abstract class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

Is it possible for me to build a class with an abstract method, say action

```
  virtual double action (int num1,int num2) const = 0;
```

and then write a member function for the same class, say eval

```
  double eval () const 
  {
   ..
   //In here we use function "action"
   ..
   }
```

Because on the one hand the class is abstract and thus I can't create instances of it, so it will never execute an abstract function. On the other hand, it might not?

The endgame with this question is to not write down the function in the further classes that will inherit my class, and it seems useful to write the function eval only once yet different action functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is legal. If `action` is called from within `eval`, it will dispatch to the final overrider in the dynamic type of the actual object on which `eval` is being called, which is necessarily of a concrete (not abstract) type.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :) will accept the answer as soon as this site will let me to

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it and this is called the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). The name is rather confusing, because there are no templates (in the c++ sense) involved. It can be useful if subclasses specialize parts of some bigger calculation (eg. as in your example).

Comment: not sure why downvote, if there is something wrong with this answer i would like to know what..